# UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\ue13b' in position 25: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python, character-encoding, locale

**Error**:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\ue13b' in position 25: illegal multibyte sequence
```

The file encoding format is utf-8, and there is an unrecognized word in the file when it is read.  ‘左足趾麻木’

**Code**:

```
for line in open(label_filepath, encoding='utf-8'):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the native encoding to utf-8

```
import sys
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(buffer=sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening when Python tries to print.  When printing, that is writing to [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.stdout), Python encodes the text to be printed with the encoding expected by the terminal.  In this case the system encoding is *gbk*, but *gbk* is unable to encode the third character in the string (`'\ue13b'`), so the `UnicodeEncodeException` is raised.

One solution would be to set the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable to UTF-8 when you call Python:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python myscript.py
```

If you are using a unix-like operating system you could change your locale from a gbk locale to a utf-8 locale, for example from `zh_CN.gbk` to `zh_CN.utf8` (this will affect how all programs read and write from files, so this may not be a good idea if you have a lot of *gbk*-encoded data).

If you are using Windows, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console) for information about working with unicode in the Windows terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If it's caused by the editor you are using, for example. Try to add a line to the file "Python.sublime-build". It worked on mine.

[reference](https://blog.csdn.net/acsunqi/article/details/50812469)

[image]