# Why do different python versions have different behaviors on stand output print?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, stdout, python-3.4, python-3.8

The Python 3.4 and Python 3.8/3.9 are different when I try execute below statement:

```py
print('\u212B')
```

Python 3.8/3.9 can print it correctly.

```
Å
```

Python 3.4 will report an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print('\u212B')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u212b' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

And according to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60629961/8717538), I can avoid the exception by overwrite sys.stdout via statement:

```py
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(buffer=sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf-8')
```

But python 3.4 still print different charactor as below:

```
鈩?
```

So my questions are:

1. Why do different python versions have different behaviors on stand output print?
2. How can I print correct value `Å` in python 3.4?

---

Edit 1:

I guess the difference is caused by [PEP 528 -- Change Windows console encoding to UTF-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0528). But I still don't understand the machanism of console encoding and how I can print correct character in Python 3.4.

---

Edit 2:

One more difference, `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` will get `utf-8` in Python 3.8/3.9 and get `mbcs` in Python 3.4.

Comment: Your *system/console* appears to be set to GBK and is thus not handling the output correctly. Not a Python version difference, but an environmental difference.

Comment: @deceze I run them on same environment except python version.

Comment: And what environment is that exactly?

Comment: @deceze windows 10, `platform.platform()` print `Windows-10-10.0.17134`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why?

Regarding the rationale behind the `stdout` encoding you can read more in the answers here: [Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)

In short, Python 3.4 is using your OS's encoding by default as the one for `stdout` whereas with Python 3.8 it is set to UTF-8.

#### How to fix this?

You can use a new method - [`reconfigure`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure) introduced with Python 3.7:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

Typically, you can try setting the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING` to `utf-8`:

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

in most of the operating systems except Windows [where another environment variable must be set for it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/6573902):

```
set PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSIOENCODING=1
```

You can [fix it in the version of Python preceding v. 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539882/whats-the-deal-with-python-3-4-unicode-different-languages-and-windows/30551552#30551552) via installing  `win-unicode-console` package that handles UTF issues transparently on Windows:

```
pip install win-unicode-console
```

If you are not running the code directly from a console there is a possibility that your [IDE configuration is interfering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955589/python-3-4-encoding-in-windows-8-1).

Comment: I tried this method. Python 3.4 still print `鈩?` but not the correct `Å`